# How to increase the screen buffer size on a minicom session screen

Tags: ssh

I have been trying to increase the buffer size on the router cli which I am connected through a serial cable via minicom session but I am unable to do it. I am connecting to a linux server through ssh and then connecting to a Juniper router via the server using the command **minicom -b 115200**. I have very minimal buffer on the router's cli and want to max it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry, applications and their configuration are off-topic here, see the [help].

Answer (score 2):

Start minicom with parameter -s:

```
minicom -s
```

Then go to

```
Screen and keyboard
```

and here you can see

```
K - History Buffer Size    : 2000
```

On your Juniper you can set:

```
set cli screen-length
```

Default value is 24.

Comment: The maximum number I could set for K - History Buffer Size was 9999. I saved that number but I see no change in the screen buffer size. Am I doing something wrong?